# I want action bar with fragment in viewPager

Tags: android

Im using view pager for that i used 3 fragments. but when my activity get started it open the first fragment without action bar.i want to display action bar for each fragment..Can any one help me for this??

Comment: Use a `FrameLayout` in your `activity_layout` and put your Fragments there

Comment: Refer to this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar

Comment: I used Framelayout but then also im not getting action bar...for solution  i hide action bar from style  and used tool bar in main_activity